# Glassfish does not find setter method of taglib

Tags: java, glassfish

I have read many other articles in StackOverflow, but none of them considers my case.

I have a java web project in which there is a tag with the attribute "Height" with the first letter capitalized. In the java class I have the "`setHeight`" method, but when I call the tag running the application in Glassfish 5.0 with Java 8.0.152, it launches the error "Cannot find a setter method for the attribute Height". This same code works correctly on the JRun application server with Java 6.0.45.

I would like not to have to change the name of the attribute, as it is called from many `jsp`.

What setter method is Glassfish waiting for? I've tried these and none of them work:

> - setHeight
> - setheight
> - settheight
> - sethheight
> - settHeight
> - setHheight
> - sethHeight
> - set_height
> - set_Height
> - sethEight

Thank you very much in advance.

This is my code:

/test.tld

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <!DOCTYPE taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD JSP Tag Library 1.1//EN"  "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-jsptaglibrary_1_1.dtd">
    <taglib>
        <tlibversion>1.0</tlibversion>
        <jspversion>1.1</jspversion>
        <shortname>Test tag</shortname>
        <info/>
        <tag>
            <name>DataTable</name>
            <tagclass>com.test.taglib.DataTableTag</tagclass>
            <bodycontent>JSP</bodycontent>
            <attribute>
                <name>Height</name>
                <required>false</required>
                <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
            </attribute>
        </tag>
    </taglib>
```

/test.java

```
    private String Height;

    public void setHeight(String sHeight) {
        this.Height = sHeight;
    }
```

/test.jsp

```
    <test:DataTable  Height="50">lorem ipsum</test:DataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your property name must start with lower case character:

```
private String height;

public void setHeight(String sHeight) {
    this.height = sHeight;
}
```

Because the naming conventions says that the variable Name must start with lower case character, the setter is than set+first char uppercase ...
And this is the way how El works.

For more infoemations see https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @Jens.
I've already checked that and it does not affect anything.
The attribute of the tag (test.tld) starts with uppercase letters and with this attribute is that with it the setter method is generated, and I need this attribute to start with a capital letter.
Do you know if this is possible in Glassfish? In Jrun it works correctly.